# Xilinx 14.7 license configuration manager is not running

Tags: xilinx-ise

I have installed Xilinx 14.7 but I'm unable to open its configuration manager even after several trials to put in a license as Xilinx gives me this error:

> ERROR:Map:258: - A problem was encountered attempting to get the license for this architecture.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Xilinx requires a license file or license server to complete the Map stage.  If you purchased a Xilinx development board, they usually include a node-locked license file (*.lic).  To get that work, create an environment variable to point to the location of the *.lic or the license server.

Comment: Do you have a license for Xilinx ISE?

Comment: no I think I don't have one ,how can I get it? as the license manager isn't opening at all

Answer (score 1):

You can get the license here:

https://www.xilinx.com/support/licensing_solution_center.html

Once you download the license file (it will have the `.lic` file extension) you can place it in the `.../Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/coregen/core_licenses` directory

The exact path to where you need to put it depends on where you installed the software. I installed mine to `/opt/` so my path would be `/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/coregen/core_licenses`